# A non-convex optimization problem

Tags: optimization, operations-research, non-convex-optimization

Given matrices ${\bf A} \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ and ${\bf B} \in \mathbb R^{p \times n}$ and scalar $c \in \mathbb R$,

$$\begin{aligned}
  &\underset{{\bf x}, {\bf y} \in \mathbb R^n}{\text{minimize}}  & &  {\bf x}^\top {\bf y} \\
  &\text{subject to}& & {\bf A} {\bf y} \preceq {\bf 0}_m, \quad \| {\bf B} {\bf x} \|_2 \leq c \\ 
  \end{aligned}$$

What makes this problem non-convex is that fact that both variables $\bf x$ and $\bf y$ are multiplied together in the objective. I am looking for suggestions and resources to tackle the non-convex optimization problem above, which I came across at work. Any help is appreciated.

---

**Motivation**

This is a problem in transportation flow optimization, where $\bf x$ are the returns and $\bf y$ are the desired weights. The objective is to maximize the total return subject to linear constraints on weights and a norm constraint on the returns vector.

Comment: What do you mean by $Ay \preceq 0$?

Comment: does the edit help? it means each component is non-positive.

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: It is a problem in transportation flow optimization. y is the desired weights, and x are the returns. the objective is to maximize total returns, based on linear constraints on weights and norm constraint on the return vector. I am not sure, if there is a good answer for it, so just asking here the experts if they know of anything similar.

Comment: If you square the norm constraint, you have a non-convex [QCQP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program)